# Jumping letters and words

Tags: microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer

Here´s a strange phenomenon I´m up against when writing on my computer.  The letters tend to jump away from me which they do very frequently.  Now at this very moment things seem to go normal, and I wish it would stay that way.

So I try to write on a little to see how “normal” things are.    It certainly happens when I´m on the internet or writing the word program.  It also goes crazy when I move into a newspaper´s debate program where columns are open to participate in the debate.  It has happened during this brief process also,  things are not normal.

As I said the letters jump away from me to be seen in a different paragraph, -  I  have to make adjustments all the time.

I trust you can help me.

Below you see how badly I succeed in writing Joh. 3:16.
“For God so loved theperish but have eternal lifenot hosoever believeth in Him should  world that He gave his only son that

Comment: It looks just more like you need to pay more attention when typing, try using a live OS and typing with that, or another computer all together, does the problem still persist.

Comment: Is it a laptop? I guess you're accidentally touching the touchpad and thus clicking somewhere else in the text while typing.